# Old Style URL for Controller actions in ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC

Tags: url, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-mvc

I am migrating my REST APIs developed with ASP.NET WebAPI 2. In this implementation I used the old style urls for my action such as

http://example.com/apiserver/api/v1/members/getbynumber?membershipNo=109900036319
But when migrating to the .Net core 2.0 I see the default url style for action is like http://example.com/apiserver/api/v1/members/109900036319 and I don't see any example on how to use the old style.

How can I set which one I want to use or support both schemes.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a `MembersController` and a `GetByNumber` action:

```
[Route("api/v1/[controller]/[action]")]
public MembersController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("")]
    public IActionResult GetByNumber(long membershipNo)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Here the `RouteAttribute` on the controller sets up the URL prefix for all actions such that they will be */api/v1/members/actionname*.

If you also want lowercase URLs, add the following in `ConfigureServices` in `Startup`:

```
services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);
```

If you want, you can also specify that route template in the MVC middleware route builder.

Comment: If you can, can you mark the answer as accepted? It will help others with a similar problem find it.